# Search and replace regex over multiple files (large data)

Tags: ruby, regex, linux, perl, sed

I have the following piece of code that is repeated in several files:

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row"> (some php code) </th>
    <td>
         (more php and html)
    </td>
</tr>
```

There may be some whitespace before/after tr, th or td tags.

What tool and regex shall I use in order to replace it with the following:

```
<div class="row">
    $1
    $2
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: don't use regexp to search/replace/parse html or xml.

Comment: @blueberryfields - that's a valid concern and I've commented on that below. However, in this particular case I'd say that using regex was acceptable, considering that I essentially wanted a quick way to do three simple search/replace operations on a large number of files. There was no nesting involved in this case.

Comment: maybe add a note to that effect into your question (ie, "i know this is generally speaking a bad idea, but i'm certain this use is an acceptable exception")? this is such an incredibly common pitfall for developers, leading to such a high amount of wasted time, that it's worth the extra effort to prevent others from falling into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl has a **-0777** command line option to let you read the whole thing into memory. Once you’ve done that, you can use a substitution that uses `\s*` for whitespace and it will cross newline boundaries.  If you use `.`, make sure to use `/s` on the end of the substitution.

I can’t really tell what you want to match, but the general principle is:

```
perl -0777 -i.orig -pe 's/foo/bar/gs' file1 file2 file3
```

Answer (score 4):

For the ∞<sup>th</sup> time, do not use regex to parse HTML. Use an HTML parser.

In perl, that means using a module such as [Web::Scraper](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/Web-Scraper/Web/Scraper.html).

Comment: I have a special dispensation. :)

Comment: This was a one-time thing, so I was looking for the shortest solution possible. Otherwise I wouldn't have done it with a regex :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this will `awk` as well. First set record separator to `</tr>`, then find the opening tag `<tr>` as well as the search string. Let's say your search string is "more html code".

```
v="my new string"
awk -vRS="</tr>" -v newstring="$v" '/<tr>/ && /more html code/{ $0=newstring}{print $0>FILENAME}' file
```

Another alternative to Perl, similar to your accepted answer

```
ruby -0777 -i.orig -pe 's/foo/bar/gs' file1 file2 file3
```